# How to get rid of "Finish Setting Up Your iPhone" badge?

Tags: ios, apple-pay

I upgraded to iOS 11.2.

There is now a red badge under `Settings` on "Finish Setting Up Your iPhone.

Under `Settings>Finish Setting Up Your iPhone` there are two apparent options:

- `Back`, and
- `Set Up Apple Pay`

**How do I decline Apple's invitation to manage my financial transactions and mine them for data?**

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to `Settings>YOUR_APPLE_NAME_HERE` and click `Sign Out` if you have not already.
2. Go to `Settings>Finish Setting Up Your iPhone` and click `Set Up Apple Pay`.
3. Enter a fake Apple ID and/or password and submit. You will be told that one or both the Apple ID or password you entered was not found.
4. At this point there will be a `Cancel` button in the top left: click it.

The annoying red badge and the `Finish Setting Up Your iPhone` option should both be gone.

Answer (score 2):

After restoring my iPhone from a backup using iTunes, I was already signed into iCloud with my Apple ID. Yet I had this "Finish Setting Up Your iPhone" message and badge on the Settings app, which was super annoying. Whenever I tried to "finish" the setup, the set up would never finish because I was already signed in!

To resolve this (**make sure you have a backup** of your data before proceeding!), do the following:

1. Settings > Your Name > **Sign out**

   - Enter your password (this will turn off Find My iPhone which is ok)
   - You will be asked what info your want to keep on device. I didn't keep anything because I backed up my phone before this using iTunes.
2. Settings > **Finish Setting Up Your iPhone**

   - Follow the process, sign in with your Apple ID and password and finish all the steps.

Now everything works and there is no more red notification icon on the settings app on the home screen!

Comment: Lexible's question clearly states he wants to opt-OUT of these Apple steps.  Your answer is the opposite of that.

Comment: The first time the "Apple Pay" prompt appears there are actually three options - these correspond to "set it up now", "set it up later" and "cancel".  Does "cancel" really cancel?  If it does, it would answer the original question.   Unfortunately, Apple don't always honour requests like "I don't want to do that - now, or ever".